# schedule a job everyday, everyhour using jil

Tags: java, cron, jobs, autosys, jil

I have to schedule a job that have to run every day every hour using jil script? Can I write

```
start_time:"00:00,01:00,02:00,03:00,04:00,05:00,06:00...,22:00,23:00"
```

Is the above format right?